# How to make Image scroll like Slot Machine using animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have static ImageView, and its content's changed randomly when I click a button.
How to make Image roll like this:
[image: rolling dice]

```
public void changeImage() {
    int pickedNumber = FunctionUtils.randomInRange(arrImgList.size());

    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrImgList.get(pickedNumber));
    img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count < 30) {
                changeImage();
                count++;
            }
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

i want to add effect when changing image:

```
    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrImgList.get(pickedNumber));
    img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Comment: i want image changing effect like this. Thank sir.

Comment: i can't use gif because my image is added by user.

Comment: have you tried jquery animate?

Comment: i'm junior developer, i don't know how to use animation. 
Let me search jquery animate.

Comment: please do research and post your answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i using Android Wheel at: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
My adapter:

```
private class SlotMachineAdapter extends AbstractWheelAdapter {
    // Layout inflater
    private Context context;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SlotMachineAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return arrImgList.size();
    }

    // Layout params for image view
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView img;

        if (cachedView != null) {
            img = (ImageView) cachedView;
        } else {
            img = new ImageView(context);
        }

        img.setLayoutParams(params);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrImgList.get(index));
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, widthWheel, heightWheel, true);
        bitmap.recycle();

        img.setImageBitmap(scaled);

        return img;
    }
}
```